# How to enable typing both , and . then formatting it to . for DataGridColumn in all cultures?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

I need to accept both `,` and `.` in editable DataGridColumn regardless of culture. When value is typed it's formatted to use `.` as decimal separator.

Currently I just use:

```
<DataGridTextColumn Header="{StaticResource XpStrSize}" Binding="{Binding Size}" IsReadOnly="False"/>
```

bound property Size in ViewModel is of type double.

So if user enters 100,3 it should be updated as 100.3 in bound property. He can also enter 2.0 which should be 2.0. Moreover when user enters 100,3 it is updated in the column as 100.3 when focus leaves the field.

Comment: Are you going to accept `','` as a digit separator as well?

Comment: no. only for decimal . good point. in my culture those are not used

Comment: Then just use `string formatted = raw.Replace(',', '.');`

Comment: where? I use MVVM and bound property is type double. I would like to solve this in XAML or some more elegant way than changing the type of bound property to string.

Comment: I'm not sure if there's a way to do it just in XAML, so if someone more knowledgeable than me on the subject comes along, maybe they can say. Otherwise, you'll probably have to code a custom `BindingConverter` to do the conversion.

Comment: @matti show example of entered size and desired result

Comment: sorry @Nkosi, not sure if i understood, but i edit my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You experience the limits when you bind a double (or int) to a `TextBox` (which is created by the `DataGridTextColumn` in editing mode): you have only limited influence of foreward and backward conversion from and to a string. One solution to get more control is to introduce a new property which is of type string and represents your double as a string in a format you want. You bind this new property in XAML and do the rest of the magic (foreward, backward conversion) in your viewmodel. Both properties update each other when changed. In other words: the string for the XAML, the double for the model and the viewmodel connects both:

XAML:

```
<DataGridTextColumn Header="{StaticResource XpStrSize}" Binding="{Binding SizeAsString}" IsReadOnly
```

Viewmodel:

```
private double size;

public double Size
{
    get
    {
        return size;
    }
    set
    {
        size = value;
        NotifyPropertyChanged ();

        sizeAsString = FormatTheDoubleAccordingYourRequirements (size);
        NotifyPropertyChanged ("SizeAsString");
    }
}

private string sizeAsString;

public string SizeAsString
{
    get
    {
        return sizeAsString;
    }
    set
    {
        sizeAsString = value;
        Size = ParseTheStringAccordingYourRequirements (sizeAsString);
        NotifyPropertyChanged ();
    }
}
```

Comment: Doesn't this allow anything to be written in textbox in column?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean with you question. With this approach the `DataGridTextColumn` "sees" a string only to be edited. But your master is a double and you convert it back and forth. The string gives you all the flexibility you need. Btw, doing it this way is some sort of standard when it comes to sophisticated data validation during editing.

Comment: i mean that if i just bind to double i get red borders around textbox if it's not legal double. isn't this also an infinite loop? execution goes from set to set inifinitely?

Comment: I'm sorry you are absolutely right it was an endless Loop. I modified my answer. But usually the idea I try to show needs to be adapted to each specific situation. Yes, you lose data validation when binding to a string. Unfortunately you are in a take-all-or-nothing-situation.

Comment: thanks! yes, with simple solution i lose the data validation. however this can be done for sure. i'm currently trying to implement this thing with double property and Converter in binding that throws exception and i'm checking if setting ValidatesOnExceptions=True for the column is something to look into.

Answer (score 0):

This should work with all cultures. Far from perfect but meets minimal requirements.

So my "validation" is only to change incorrect value (like 3.0h or ere) to 1.0

xaml:

```
<DataGrid.Resources>
    <cnv:DoubleToTextConverter x:Key="DoubleToTextConverter" />
    <sys:Double x:Key="DoubleOne">1.0</sys:Double>
</DataGrid.Resources>
<!-- ... -->
    <DataGridTextColumn Header="{StaticResource XpStrSize}" Binding="{Binding Size, Converter={StaticResource DoubleToTextConverter}, ConverterParameter={StaticResource DoubleOne}, UpdateSourceTrigger=LostFocus}" IsReadOnly="False"/>
```

converter:

```
public class DoubleToTextConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter,
        System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return ((double) value).ToString("0.0", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter,
        System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        double doubleValue;
        if (double.TryParse(value.ToString().Replace(',', '.'), NumberStyles.AllowDecimalPoint, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
            out doubleValue))
        {
            return doubleValue;
        }
        if (parameter != null && parameter is double)
            return (double)parameter;

        return 0.0;
    }
}
```

property in ViewModel is still double. No additional string property needed.

Comment: why downvote? honest question. i have no idea what is wrong with this.

Answer (score 0):

Please use below code, thats work:

```
public partial class MainWindow:Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent ();

        List<MyClass> myClasses=new List<MyClass> ();
        dataGrid.ItemsSource=myClasses;
    }
}

public class MyClass
{
    public double Size { get; set; }
}

public class SizeConverter:IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value,Type targetType,object parameter,System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return System.Convert.ToString (value);
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value,Type targetType,object parameter,System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        try
        {
            string size=System.Convert.ToString (value);
            string[] s=size.Split (',');
            if (s.Count ()==2)
                return System.Convert.ToDouble (s[0]+'.'+s[1]);
            else
                return System.Convert.ToDouble (value);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show (e.Message);
        }
        return 0;
    }
}
```

xaml:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <sc:SizeConverter x:Key="sizeConverter" />
</Window.Resources>
<Grid>
    <DataGrid Name="dataGrid" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Size" Binding="{Binding Path=Size,Converter={StaticResource sizeConverter}}"  />
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
</Grid>
```